# How to update the state array?

Tags: reactjs

I have a `state` of the component like this:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state={
      editableComparatorIndexes: []
   }
}
```

And i am having trouble updating the `state`, i need to do something like this:

```
onEditComparatorClicked(i) {
     this.setState({editableComparatorIndexes[i]:1});
     this.setState(this.state);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create a copy of `state array` then update the value then use `setState` to update the state value.

By using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
onEditComparatorClicked(i) {
   let editableComparatorIndexes = [...this.state.editableComparatorIndexes];
   editableComparatorIndexes[i] = 1;
   this.setState({editableComparatorIndexes});
}
```

Or you can use [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=control) also it will also return a new `array`, like this:

```
onEditComparatorClicked(i) {
   let editableComparatorIndexes = this.state.editableComparatorIndexes.slice();
   editableComparatorIndexes[i] = 1;
   this.setState({editableComparatorIndexes});
}
```

Comment: Immutable version with double [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=control): `[...this.state.editableComparatorIndexes.slice(0, i), changedElement, ...this.state.editableComparatorIndexes.slice(i + 1)]`